# Does a thread release lock if return is called?

Tags: java

As it says in the title, in the following situation, is the lock released when `return` is called?

```
public void method(){
    syncronized(lock){
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            if( something.get(i) == something_else)
                return;
    }

    more code...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

> [A synchronized statement acquires a mutual-exclusion lock (§17.1) on
>   behalf of the executing thread, executes a block, **then releases the
>   lock.**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19)

The `return` statement [completes the execution of the block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1).